# JavaScript event handling with document.getElementById & (e) - what does (e) signify?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("bouton")
  .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    alert("Evènement : " + 
      e.type + 
      "   texte de la cible : " + 
      e.target.textContent);});
```

What mean this (e) in js ?

Comment: Information about the event been sent to your callback.   But it doesn't have to be `e`, it could be `x`, `y`, `event`, `info`..  etc

Comment: In addition to @Keith's comment: have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)